# Ubuntu Server 18.04 taking very long to boot up

Tags: ubuntu, boot, kernel, time

I've installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 as a VM to use as a web server and it's taking very long to boot up. During the booting process 100 seconds go by without any notice of what's happening and then the boot process continues apparently normally and everything seems to work ok. I have several 16.04 in production and this doesn't happen with them.

Here's part of dmesg output, the issue is between 9.91 and 107.38 seconds.  I have no idea what's going on during that time:

```
    [    5.437236] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
    [    5.595979] hv_utils: Registering HyperV Utility Driver
    [    5.601516] scsi host3: storvsc_host_t
    [    5.603642] input: Microsoft Vmbus HID-compliant Mouse as /devices/0006:045E:0621.0001/input/input4
    [    5.604162] hid 0006:045E:0621.0001: input: <UNKNOWN> HID v0.01 Mouse [Microsoft Vmbus HID-compliant Mouse] on
    [    5.628020] psmouse serio1: trackpoint: failed to get extended button data, assuming 3 buttons
    [    5.687359] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_util
    [    5.703794] hv_utils: Heartbeat IC version 3.0
    [    5.723355] hv_utils: Shutdown IC version 3.0
    [    5.736464] hv_utils: TimeSync IC version 3.0
    [    5.752895] hv_utils: VSS IC version 5.0
    [    7.876183] random: crng init done
    [    9.916153] psmouse serio1: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x01, buttons: 3/3
    [    9.918321] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3      
    [  107.456011] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  6011 MB/s
    [  107.520013] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 10094 MB/s
    [  107.584007] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  6636 MB/s
    [  107.648010] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 12081 MB/s
    [  107.728009] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  7607 MB/s
    [  107.812007] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 16748 MB/s
    [  107.884006] raid6: avx2x1   xor() 11320 MB/s
    [  107.948008] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 19159 MB/s
    [  108.012007] raid6: avx2x2   xor() 11900 MB/s
    [  108.076005] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 22272 MB/s
    [  108.140008] raid6: avx2x4   xor() 14181 MB/s
    [  108.159630] raid6: using algorithm avx2x4 gen() 22272 MB/s
    [  108.182276] raid6: .... xor() 14181 MB/s, rmw enabled
    [  108.200728] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
    [  108.245762] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx
    [  108.287018] async_tx: api initialized (async)
    [  108.643865] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
    [  108.896072] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
    [  108.900007] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
    [  109.032390] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    [  109.364683] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
    [  109.402600] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
    [  109.425550] systemd[1]: Detected virtualization microsoft.
    [  109.457009] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed VM Ware tools? I solved my problem under "Fusion" with this article: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1022525

Comment: It's going to be of relevance what hardware it is running on. Have you tried dual booting 16.04 and 18.04 on the same machine to verify that this problem is reproducible?